# Collapsing java syntax to single line

Tags: java, syntax, if-statement, formatting, string-formatting

The following ensures an output of char(4), so that 5 is 0005 and 43 is 0043:

```
if ( var > 1 && var <= 9 ) {
    o.setOutput (String.format ("%0001d", i.getInput());
else if (var > 9 && var <= 99 ) {
    o.setOutput (String.format ("%002d", i.getInput());
else if (var > 99 && var <= 999 ) {
    o.setOutput (String.format ("%03d", i.getInput());
else if (var > 999 & var <=9999 ) {
    o.setOutput (String.format ("%4d", i.getInput());
}
```

Is there any way to write this is just ONE line instead of multiple if/case statements?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to ? I appreciate the above is a little verbose/repetitive, but I think a one-line version might be a little obfuscated. You should write code to be *read*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want simply:

```
o.setOutput (String.format ("%04d", i.getInput());
```

The format string `%04d` produces an output field of (at least) four characters, padded on the left with `0` characters as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `String.format("%04d", number);`